# Get the value of an input when the radio next to it is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to get the input value if the radio beside it is checked. The Inputs and radios are in a table.

1. store all possible options inside an options array

```js
$('#table tr').each(function(index) {
  console.log("index" + index);

  if ($(this).has("input:radio")) {
    $(this).find('input:text').each(function() {
      options.push($(this).val());
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="cell">
    <td>
      <input type="radio">
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

2. get the correct answers with a combination of the two indexes (index and i)

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the text input next to the clicked radio input, you could listen for the change event:

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {...});
```

In the attached event handler you could get the index of the associated table row with the `parents()` function, which accepts a selector:

```js
const cell_index = $(this).parents('tr').index();
```

and get the value of the desired text input with the `siblings()` function, which also accepts a selector:

```js
const text_value = $(this).siblings('input[type="text"]').val();
```

Then you can store the value in your options array with the index as key:

```js
options[cell_index] = text_value;
```

and get the right answer with the array data...

**Working example:**

```js
let options = [];

$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
  const cell_index = $(this).parents('tr').index();
  const text_value = $(this).siblings('input[type="text"]').val();
  options[cell_index] = text_value;
  
  console.log('index: ' + cell_index + ' / value: ' + options[cell_index]);

  //your code to get the right answer from the array
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="cell">
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="answer">
      <input type="text" value="Miau">
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr class="cell">
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="answer">
      <input type="text" value="Bark">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks that solved it. Wasn't aware of the siblings function